# Cross Server Communication with Discord in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a bot that allows you to send messages from one server to another through the bot. I need to know how to send messages to a specific server and channel that the user specifies in the command.

What I have so far

```
import discord
import random

TOKEN = 

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    command = str(message.content).split('/')[0]
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    if command == 'send':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hello {username}!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm misinterpreting something; can you point to where in this code you've provided that constitutes your attempt at meeting the cross-server messaging requirement you described, per [ask]?

Comment: That's the thing. I have no idea where to start. I'm new to making discord bots, and don't know the things I can do yet. Inside the "if command == 'send':" I want it to send a message to another server, but I don't know how to do that. Once I know how to, I can work from there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be a using a single channel in both servers for the cross-server chat.

```py
id1 = 123456
id2 = 178228

if message.channel.id == id1:
    await client.get_channel(id2).send(message.content)
elif message.channel.id == id2:
    await client.get_channel(id1).send(message.content)
```

a "shorter" solution will be

```py
id_channel={123456:178228,178228:123456}
await client.get_channel(id_channel(message.channel.id)).send(message.content)
```

for more connections, you could use a list with id pairs for messaging
or define a class for conversations which would be easier to use and change later on